# .NET SMO stored procedure scripts mysteriously changed

Tags: c#, .net, smo

We've been using .NET's Sql Server Management Objects (SMO) to maintain our database scripts (which serve as both install and upgrade scripts).  For some stored procedures, we like to have default implementations which can later be customized at the customer's discretion.  So, in our install/upgrade script, we had something like so:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[STORED_PROC_NAME]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STORED_PROC_NAME] @yada varchar(50),....
AS
BEGIN
     yada yada yada definition here is within the string passed to executesql
END'
END
```

Note how the entire definition is located within the string passed to sp_executesql.

This works well since the procedure is not changed if it already existed.  However, at some point within the last few days, the scripts generated by SMO have changed to the following format:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[STORED_PROC_NAME]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
BEGIN
EXEC dbo.sp_executesql @statement = N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[STORED_PROC_NAME] AS'
END

GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[STORED_PROC_NAME] @yada varchar(50), ...
BEGIN
     yada yada yada this definition is now non-dynamic sql
END
```

This is obviously cleaner from a readability standpoint since the procedure definition is not located within a string, but now this script will alter stored procedures that already exist.  What changed?  Code that generated the script below:

```
Scripter scrp = new Scripter(serv);
scrp.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;  //important
scrp.Options.NoCollation = true;

scrp.Options.Encoding = Encoding.Unicode;

scrp.Options.Bindings = true;
scrp.Options.ClusteredIndexes = true;
scrp.Options.DriChecks = true;
scrp.Options.DriClustered = true;
scrp.Options.DriDefaults = true;
scrp.Options.DriForeignKeys = false;
scrp.Options.DriIndexes = true;
scrp.Options.DriNonClustered = true;
scrp.Options.DriPrimaryKey = true;
scrp.Options.DriUniqueKeys = true;

scrp.Options.FullTextIndexes = true;
scrp.Options.Indexes = true;
scrp.Options.NonClusteredIndexes = true;
scrp.Options.Triggers = false;


foreach (String s in scrp.Script(new Urn[] { source.StoredProcedures["STORED_PROC_NAME"].Urn }))
{
    file.WriteLine(s);
    file.WriteLine("GO");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your code did not change, I would have to guess that the library you are referencing changed. Are you now referencing a different version of the SMO library?

Comment: Definitely not.  This is probably poor practice, but when we make changes to the scripting software we just move the .exe to the appropriate directory in the other projects (which have copies of all of the Microsoft.SqlServer.* dlls -- these have never changed).  EDIT: Cancel that, got my projects mixed up.  It appears it's using references out of the GAC, so it's possible

Comment: Well it seems to me like there's three pieces here: your database, your application code and the libraries being used by your application code to generate the script. If the output of your application has changed, I feel like one of those would have had to change.

Comment: I would accept this answer, but I don't have enough reputation.  After digging around I found out that the Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo.dll changed from version 11 to 12 (Sql Server 2012 to Sql Server 2014, I believe) to change the type of scripts that are generated when IncludeIfNotExists = true.  Ugh, thanks man.

Comment: No worries! If you can't accept the answer an upvote would still be great :-)